# Building cross platform sources with android.mk in NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to build some cross platform cpp files in my android mk file. These sources are not in sub directories of the jni directory.

Currently i have something like below, is there some way to avoid the long relative paths to describe where the source files are located? What is best practice here?

Thanks

```
   LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := host
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../../../Dev/common/host.c

    include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I think this will do it 

      LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../Dev/common/host.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own variables in mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

SRC_ROOT := ../../../../../Dev

LOCAL_MODULE    := host
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SRC_ROOT)/common/host.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: sorry, this does not recurse backwards, it seems to append ../../../../../Dev onto the local_path